# implementing cantor pairing function in iOS

Tags: ios, math, mapping, square-root

I have a implementation of the **Cantor Pairing Function** in Java which I wrote 
2 years ago. Now then I'm moving more to iOS I need the same thing in Objective-C.

The problem is, at least from my point of view, in Java I had to implement a **BigSqrt** Class 
which I did by my self. Because theoreticaly I can now Pair any size of number.

Because I am new to iOS I really do not know if I have to implement all the things again for objective-C or is there something already implemented. If so, could someone give me a hint where to start implementing the **Cantor Pairing function** for any size of "Integer" in **Objective-C** ?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

I used this to set tags on tableview cells:

```
NSUInteger cantorPair(NSIndexPath *indexPath)
{
    NSUInteger x = indexPath.section;
    NSUInteger y = indexPath.row;
    return ((x + y) * (x + y + 1)) / 2 + y;
}


NSIndexPath *reverseCantorPair(NSUInteger z)
{
    NSUInteger t = floor((-1.0f + sqrt(1.0f + 8.0f * z))/2.0f);
    NSUInteger x = t * (t + 3) / 2 - z;
    NSUInteger y = z - t * (t + 1) / 2;
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:y inSection:x];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is for a C# version, but should be almost identical in Objective-C:

http://sachiniscool.blogspot.com/2011/06/cantor-pairing-function-and-reversal.html

```
int CantorPair(short x, short y)
{
    return ((x + y) * (x + y + 1)) / 2 + y;
}
```

and to reverse the pairing

```
short[] Reverse(int z)
{
    short[] pair = new short[2];
    int t = (int)Math.Floor((-1D + Math.Sqrt(1D + 8 * z))/2D);
    int x = t * (t + 3) / 2 - z;
    int y = z - t * (t + 1) / 2;
    pair[0] = (short)x;
    pair[1] = (short)y;
    return pair;
}
```

Comment: sweet but does the Math.sqrt can handle "BigIntegers", sorry I am not into C#.